# Formal verification of security protocols

Tags: protocols, formal-verification

When you try to verify security protocols you have to do a lot of different steps like formalizing a simpler version based on a extremely complex real protocol using some extended Dolev Yao model. Afterwards you have to look for a tool and a programming language to map your algebraic model to it like "*.csp".
Somewhere in between you have to limit the capabilities of the attacker and sometimes even the all the other participants/agents without removing parts of the protocol that could possibly reveal vulnerabilities of the protocol.

What are the most difficult steps - regarding time - trial and error processes and so on when trying to verify a modern protocol. I don't want to know the opinion of someone who stuck in the process but more the objective view of the expected complexities of the process. Also I would like to know if I missed important steps in my description in my first paragraph.

Comment: I created the [formal-verification](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-verification) tag, thanks for mentioning that! It seems to be an [established term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) to describe what you are talking about, and I don't see any other tag that already covers it. (Note, I've edited a few other questions that I think could benefit from this tag.)